# Factorisation of block lower-triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices

I have a lower-triangular matrix $T_{ij}$ wich can be decomposed in block form (say $m\times m$) as:
\begin{eqnarray}
T=
\left(\begin{matrix}
A & ... & ...&0\\
B & A& ... & 0\\
0 & B & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & ...& B&A
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
where each $A,B$ are of dimension $N\times N$. I am facing a problem to factorise this matrix so that:
\begin{eqnarray}
F = U^{\dagger}.T.U
\end{eqnarray}
with $U$ being unitary, and where the resulting blocks of $F$ are all diagonal, that is, for arbitrary $n,k\in[0,...,m-1]$:
\begin{eqnarray}
F_{nm}=f_{ij}\delta_{ij}
\end{eqnarray}
with $i,j\in[0,N-1]$. I have tried so far to make a block decomposition as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
F_{nm} =\sum_{s=0}^{m-1}\left(U^{\dagger}_{ns}\right).A.\left(U_{sm}\right) + \sum_{s=0}^{m-2}U_{n,s+1}^{\dagger}.B.U_{s,m}
\end{eqnarray}
and now I know $F_{nm}$ is diagonal; moreover, I know the diagonal entries. However, I am still stuck on how to determine the $U$ matrix elements.

**Method tried so far:**
There are even more restrictions in the $A,B$ matrices, for instance, $A_{ij}\propto a_{ii}\delta_{ij}+ a_{i+1,i}$ with all the other elements being 0. The matrix $B$ only has a single matrix element at $B_{ij}=b\delta_{i0}\delta_{j,N-1}$. If we take that into account, an equation of the off-diagonal elements can be obtained as:
\begin{eqnarray}
(k\neq k') &&\sum_{s=0}^{m-1}\sum_{k_{1}=0}^{N-2}\left(U^{\dagger}_{nk,s,k_{1}+1}\right).a_{k_{1}+1,k_{1}}.\left(U_{s,k_{1};mk'}\right) = -\sum_{s=0}^{M-2}\left(U^{\dagger}_{nk,s+1,0}\right).b.\left(U_{s,N-1;mk'}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
and also for $k=k'$. However I don't know how to proceed from here on determining the $Q$ matrix elements, and I suspect there has to be an easier way to do this? Can anyone give some advice here? Thanks.

**EDIT**: The transformation does not need to be unitary necessarily. The structure of the $F_{nm}=B_{n,q}\delta_{n-m,q}$. This simplifies the system, as we can now write $F=U^{\dagger}.T.V$ using that:
\begin{eqnarray}
U^{\dagger}_{ns}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}e^{i2\pi(s-n)/M}U^{\dagger}_{n}; && V_{sn} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}e^{-i2\pi(s-n)/M}V_{n} 
\end{eqnarray}
and I arrive to the following system (fixed $n$, solve for all $q$):
\begin{eqnarray}
B_{q,n}e^{i2\pi q/M} = U^{\dagger}_{n}.\left[A+Be^{i2\pi/M}\right].V_{n\pm q}
\end{eqnarray}
All blocks $B_{q,n}$ are diagonal $N\times N$ complex matrices; however I don't know how to calculate the $U_{n},V_{n}$ from here. If I take $q=0$ then:
\begin{eqnarray}
B_{0n} = U_{n}^{\dagger}.( A+ Be^{i2\pi/M} ).V_{n}
\end{eqnarray}
is a diagonal matrix on the lhs. So this is a diagonalization problem if $U^{\dagger}_{n}=V_{n}$. If I try to obtain the eigenvectors with $A_{ij}\propto a_{ii}\delta_{ij}+ a_{i+1,i}$ and $B_{ij}=b\delta_{i0}\delta_{j,N-1}$,  I obtain always the zero eigenvector due to the structure of the $A+Be^{i2\pi/M}$ matrix, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this is possible (i.e. that a solution exists)? I suspect that in general, this might only be possible if $AB = BA.$

Comment: There are some reasons why I am trying this: first, the Schur decomposition of an arbitrary matrix $F$, but second noting that the equation U.F-T.U = 0 is a homogeneous Sylvester equation, which has a not trivial solution if F,T do not share any of their eigenvalues. The matrix $T$ is a lower diagonal matrix, with elements equal to 1 in the diagonal, and non-zero elements right below the diagonal, but the rest are zero.